# What does "all right" mean when placed at the end of a sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

> Those are credit cards all right.

What does that sentence mean?

- "those are credit cards, ok? not anything else you moron. Is that clear to you now?" (an impatient/~aggressive way of telling not to discuss the matter further)
- "those are real, true credit cards, not something else" (confirmation of the nature of the credit cards)
- something else?

Could there be a difference in meaning between British English and Americal English? (and possibly other English-es?)

Comment: We really need more context to interpret these words (ideally, full audio/video *including preceding conversation*). But *on average* the significance of the last two words in something like the assertion *Those are credit cards all right* is approximately the same as ***for sure*** (speaker is emphasising that there's absolutely no doubt they're credit cards). Alternatively, *when followed by a question mark*, most likely speaker is simply inviting the addressee to agree with him (a kind of "rhetorical question tag", approximately equal to ***...aren't they**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: this is a standalone sentence, followed by some generic discussion about credit cards. I was sure that the meaning was the one you mention, it is just that in French such a structure carries a harsh meaning so i wanted at least a confirmation that it can be the "confirmation" version.

Comment: Well, your text *"those are credit cards, ok? not anything else you moron* clearly matches my *second* ("rhetorical question") sense. In which context it's worth noting that ***all right*** and ***okay*** are equivalent and interchangeable with that second sense. But we wouldn't normally use ***okay*** instead of ***all right / alright*** with my first ("emphatic") sense of ***for sure, without a doubt***.

Comment: [M-W *adverb* definition 1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20right)